# Add missing rows to a table using another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `rep.Ref` containing `Date`, `Country` and `Total_Amt`. I have another table `rep.Customer` containing Date, `Country`, `Customer` and `Amt`.  If a combination of `Date` and `Country` does not exist in `rep.Customer`  for a `Customer`, then I want to insert a row into `rep.Customer` and set `Amt = NULL` for that row. I need to do this for each `Customer` where the combination of `Date` and `Country` does not exist in `rep.Customer`.

I have the below code but it does not return any rows to be inserted unless I apply filters for the specific `country` and `date` that I know are missing (I've commented these out in the code below). And even if I apply the filters the `Customer` is returned as `NULL`.

```
INSERT INTO rep.Customer (Date, Country, Customer, Amt)
SELECT oa.Date, oa.Country, dca.Customer, NULL
FROM rep.Ref oa
--FROM (select * from rep.Ref where Dest_Country = 'Chile' and Date = '2018-12-31') oa
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Date, Country, Customer
    FROM rep.Customer
    --where Date = '2018-12-31' and Country = 'Chile' and Customer = 'ABC'
) dca ON oa.Date = dca.Date
    AND oa.Country= dca.Country
WHERE dca.Customer IS NULL
```

Comment: The way code is written now it doesn't look wrong to me, so the problem is probably in the matching logic. You only check for Date / Country-combo, but shouldn't customer number be part of the join condition as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to separately select `DISTINCT Customer` and `DISTINCT Date, Country` and then cross join them before conditionally merging the resulting Customer/Date/Country combinations back into `rep.Customer`.

Try something like:

```
INSERT INTO rep.Customer (Date, Country, Customer, Amt)
SELECT dc.Date, dc.Country, c.Customer, NULL
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Date, Country
    FROM rep.Ref
) dc
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Customer
    FROM rep.Customer
) c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM rep.Customer c2
    WHERE c2.Date = dc.Date
    AND c2.Country = dc.Country
    AND c2.Customer = c.Customer
)
```

The above uses `NOT EXISTS(...)`, but a `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL` can be used also.

```
LEFT JOIN rep.Customer c2
    ON c2.Date = dc.Customer
    AND c2.Country = dc.Customer
    AND c2.Customer = c.Customer
WHERE c2.Customer IS NULL
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ke_7VGXY) for a sample execution.